# Laravel Dependency Injection in Mockery

Tags: laravel, mockery

I'm trying to write test for this repo: [laravel.com](https://github.com/laravel/laravel.com). below is the app's structure.

**App\Documentation.php**

```
public function __construct(Filesystem $files, Cache $cache)
{
   $this->files = $files;
   $this->cache = $cache;
}

public function get($version, $page)
{
    return $this->cache->remember('docs.'.$version.'.'.$page, 5, function () use ($version, $page) {
    
            if ($this->files->exists($path = $this->markdownPath($version, $page))) {
                return $this->replaceLinks($version, markdown($this->files->get($path)));
            }

            return null;
    });
}

public function markdownPath($version, $page)
{
    return base_path('resources/docs/'.$version.'/'.$page.'.md');
}
```

**DocsController.php**

```
public function __construct(Documentation $docs)
{
     $this->docs = $docs;
}

public function show($version, $page = null)
{
    $content = $this->docs->get($version, $sectionPage);
}
```

here is my test logic

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('App\Documentation')->makePartial();

$mock->shouldReceive('markdownPath')->once()->andReturn(base_path('test/stubs/stub.md'));

$this->app->instance('App\Documentation', $mock);

$this->get('docs/'.DEFAULT_VERSION.'/stub') //It hits DocsController@show
//...
```

here is the error

> Call to a member function remember() on null

**Different ways I've tried so far and different errors**

1)

```
$mock = \Mockery::mock('App\Documentation');

$mock->shouldReceive('markdownPath')->once()->andReturn(base_path('test/stubs/stub.md'));

app()->instance('App\Documentation', $mock);
```

> Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received Mockery_0_App_Documentation::get(), but no expectations were specified

Here I don't wanna define expectation for each methods.

2)

```
app()->instance('App\Documentation', \Mockery::mock('App\Documentation[markdownPath]', function ($mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('markdownPath')->once()->andReturn(base_path('test/stubs/stub.md'));
}));
```

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Documentation::__construct(), 0 passed and exactly 2 expected

If we specify method name in mock (App\Documentation[markdownPath]); the constructor is not mocking, so we get error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the container to resolve a real instance (so that the filesystem and cache dependencies are resolved), and then create a partial mock from your real instance in order to define the expectation for the `markdownPath` method. Once your mock instance is setup, put it into the container for the controller to use.

```
// Resolve a real instance from the container.
$instance = $this->app->make(\App\Documentation::class);

// Create a partial mock from the real instance.
$mock = \Mockery::mock($instance);

// Define your mock expectations.
$mock->shouldReceive('markdownPath')->once()->andReturn(base_path('test/stubs/stub.md'));

// Put your mock instance in the container.
$this->app->instance(\App\Documentation::class, $mock);
```

Comment: Tanx for feedback, but this way doen't call markdownPath from mock

``Method markdownPath(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_0_App_Documentation_App_Documentation should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.`` I used dd() in markdownPath and it executes actual code

Comment: @AmirRezaM75 It's possible that the `get()` method is finding a hit in cache, which would mean your `markdownPath()` method would never get called. As a quick test, just comment out the caching functionality in your controller and see if the mock expectation is filled.